# How to set specific days with json for datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, datepicker

I have more than one specific days in my datepicker and I set these days with array but I want to set with json instead of array (I know both of them are object). You will see below example I have specific days if you click.

so my question is how can I set my dates with json data to use specific days ?

```js
$(function() {
  var ilktarih = ['2017-03-23'];
  var sontarih = ['2017-04-10']
  var bostarihler = ['2017-03-15', '2017-03-16', '2017-03-17', '2017-03-18', '2017-03-19', '2017-03-20', '2017-03-21', '2017-03-22', '2017-03-23', '2017-03-24', '2017-03-25', '2017-03-26', '2017-03-27', '2017-03-28', '2017-03-29', '2017-03-30'];
  var dolutarihler = ['2017-02-22', '2017-02-23', '2017-02-24', '2017-02-25', '2017-02-26', '2017-02-27', '2017-02-28', '2017-03-01', '2017-03-02', '2017-03-03', '2017-03-04', '2017-03-05', '2017-03-06', '2017-03-07', '2017-03-08', '2017-03-09', '2017-03-10', '2017-03-11', '2017-03-12', '2017-03-13', '2017-03-14'];
  var sstarihler = [];

  var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
    from = $("#checkin").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      firstDay: 1,
      minDate: new Date(ilktarih),
      maxDate: new Date(sontarih),
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var yenitarih = new Date();

        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

        $("#checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
        $("#checkout").trigger("focus");
      },

      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
        var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
        var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
        if (m.length == 1) {
          m = '0' + m;
        } // append zero(0) if single digit
        if (d.length == 1) {
          d = '0' + d;
        } // append zero(0) if single digit
        var currDate = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;

        if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, dolutarihler) >= 0) {
          return [false, "ui-highlight"];
        }

        if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, bostarihler) >= 0) {
          return [true, "ui-bos"];
        }

        if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, sstarihler) >= 0) {
          return [false, "ui-ss"];
        } else {
          return [true];
        }

      },
      isTo1: true,
    }).on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }),
    to = $("#checkout").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      firstDay: 1,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      minDate: new Date(ilktarih),
      maxDate: new Date(sontarih),
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $("#checkin").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
      },
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
        var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
        var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
        if (m.length == 1) {
          m = '0' + m;
        } // append zero(0) if single digit
        if (d.length == 1) {
          d = '0' + d;
        } // append zero(0) if single digit
        var currDate = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;

        if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, dolutarihler) >= 0) {
          return [true, "ui-highlight-donus"];
        }


        if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, bostarihler) >= 0) {
          return [true, "ui-bos"];
        }


        if (jQuery.inArray(currDate, sstarihler) >= 0) {
          return [true, "ui-ss-donus"];
        } else {
          return [true];
        }

      }
    }).on("change", function() {
      from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
    });

  function getDate(element) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
    } catch (error) {
      date = null;
    }

    return date;
  }
});
```

```css
.form {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 120px auto;
}

.form input {
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ui-highlight .ui-state-default {
  background: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
  color: white !important;
  cursor: no-drop;
}

.ui-bos .ui-state-default {
  background: green !important;
  border-color: green !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.ui-ss .ui-state-default {
  background: yellow !important;
  border-color: yellow !important;
  color: gray !important;
  cursor: help;
}

.ui-ss-donus .ui-state-default {
  background: yellow !important;
  border-color: yellow !important;
  color: gray !important;
  cursor: help;
}

.ui-highlight-donus .ui-state-default {
  background: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" id="checkin" />
  <input type="text" id="checkout" />
  <input type="submit" value="Ara" />
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

my json dates

```js
{

    "ilktarih": ["2017-03-23"],
    "sontarih": ["2017-04-10"],
    "bostarihler": ["2017-03-15","2017-03-16","2017-03-17","2017-03-18","2017-03-19","2017-03-20","2017-03-21","2017-03-22","2017-03-23","2017-03-24","2017-03-25","2017-03-26","2017-03-27","2017-03-28","2017-03-29","2017-03-30"],
    "dolutarihler": ["2017-08-22","2017-06-23","2017-06-24","2017-05-25","2017-06-26","2017-10-27","2017-02-28","2017-03-01","2017-03-02","2017-03-03","2017-03-04","2017-03-05","2017-03-06","2017-03-07","2017-03-08","2017-03-09","2017-03-10","2017-03-11","2017-03-12","2017-03-13","2017-03-14"]
}
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/jmWyjm)

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking

Comment: @charlietfl I have specific day [reserved days or weekend for example] with array top of the my code and I want to use json instead of array

Comment: What does that mean exactly... *"use json instead of array"* ?? Do you mean how to request from server and then put into datapicker?

Comment: yes exactly I want to request from server and the put into datepicker.. sorry about my english

Comment: Make ajax request then initialize datepicker in success callback when you have the data

Comment: I have no any experience with json until now I tried lots of thing but I couldn't achieve I only created my dates with json and I added it end of snippet I will try thank you..